# creating html in php while loop

Tags: php, html, loops

I am looping through a recordset in php and building up the html and then returning it to the calling webpage.  However the HTML I create isn't returning and the numbers are adding together.  What silly mistake am I making.  I know the HTML basic structure is ok as hardcoded all my results in the loop.  When the recordset onlt contained a single row and this worked fine.

```
$myres ="";
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)){ 
      $myres = $myres + '<option value=' + odbc_result($result,"load_no") + '>' + odbc_result($result,"load_no") + '</option>';         
}  
echo $myres;
```

Comment: Concatenation in PHP is done using the . operator rather than +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try the following:

```
$myres ="";
  while (odbc_fetch_row($result))
  { 
      $myres = $myres . '<option value=' . odbc_result($result,"load_no") . '>' . odbc_result($result,"load_no") . '</option>';         
  }  
  echo $myres;
```

Comment: You can just do `$myres .= '<opti...`

Comment: that is also an option.. this does not mean my answer is wrong @qwertynl. I hope you understand this..

Comment: I never said it was wrong :-)

Comment: Who said ***I*** downvoted?

Comment: I don't think @qwertynl was the one who downvoted you.

Comment: @qwertynl sorry for that  I thought you have downvoted.. :)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not Javascript.

To concatenate string, use "." ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Concatenation is done using `.` and not `+` in PHP
2. Why not just do this (since you are echoing at the end anyway?):

   ```
   while (odbc_fetch_row($result)): ?>
     <option value='<?php echo odbc_result($result,"load_no")?>'>
           <?php echo odbc_result($result,"load_no")?>
     </option>     
   <?php endwhile ?>
   ```

   So much much more readable (I think)

Comment: Care to 'splain the downvote? :-)

Comment: Probably for short tags, and going in/out of PHP tags so often. This is very unreadable and not good practice to use short tags.

Comment: @Jessica I updated it out of the short tags. I never use short tags in my real code, I just thought it was a quick way to write my answer. :-D

Comment: Also I see no issue with "going in and out of php tags" What is wrong with that?

Comment: It's generally considered hard to read, it's messy.

Comment: @Jessica Actually, the `<?=` open-tag syntax is typically regarded as fine, seeing as they are distinct from "short-tags" and are not affected by the `short_open_tag` flag.

Comment: Not in any list of best practices I've ever read. Short tags are disabled by default at this point and should not be used. The short tag echo will still be enabled by default, but you shouldn't count on it. And again, I didn't downvote it, just taking a guess.

Comment: Agree to disagree then; enjoy typing `php echo`, I'll stick with `=`. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "*shouldn't count on it*"; I'd sooner recommend that people stop developing with 5.3 support in mind. Time to move on up.